# Infinite read(2) with piped command

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix

I'd like to have some precision about `read(2)` behaviour on Linux systems. I'm trying to make a shell and I got a problem while reading the input. I do something like

```
read(0, BUF, 4096);
```

So the thing is on bash (and most shell) you can pipe a command like this:

```
echo ls | bash
```

Bash will execute `ls` only once but when I do this read always return me the same buffer, `"ls"` so it goes in infinite loop.
I wanted to know why `read(2)` doesn't return me 0 thanks you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to examine [`read`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html)'s return value. If it returns 0, then it reached the end of the input stream. That is, instead of this:

```
read(0, BUF, 4096);
```

you need to write:

```
int bytes_read = read(0, BUF, 4096);
```

and then check if `bytes_read` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not clearing the buffer after each read. If there's nothing to read, `read()` will return 0 and write nothing to the buffer. If the buffer's not cleared, whatever was in it before hand will still be there, which is why you keep getting your infinite `ls` - there's still only the original `ls` in there, but you keep treating it as new input.

Comment: This answer is correct in the sense that it explains the observed behavior, but it is misleading in that it makes it sound like the fix is to clear the buffer.  Of course the right fix is to examine the return value of `read`.